# Use of MOREOVER

Tags: word-usage

My English literature teacher says "moreover" should be used only when you write a lengthy passage, such as a dissertation, to add an extra point after many points have been written. Is that true?

Comment: Broadly, yes, but it's a question of style, opinion, not fact. The only facts we can relate to you are how the word has been used, both popularly and by well-known authors, which broadly correspond to your teacher's advice.

Comment: Broadly, yes, but here's (arguably) a counterexample: 'Mortgage insurance is not always needed, even when a borrower has little money for a down payment. Moreover, it's costly ...'. ([NYTimes_realestate](http://www.nytimes.com/1994/11/20/realestate/getting-through-the-maze-of-mortgage-insurance.html?pagewanted=all)). A better caveat is 'Only use in formal statements where a certain gravitas is an advantage rather than an incongruity'.

Comment: so is it not common for native English speakers to use "moreover" in, say, the first 1000 words of their writings?

Comment: It doesn't really matter whether it's used in the beginning or at the end of a text, as long as it fits. What matters is that the word is used, like EdwinAshworth said, in formal statements.

Comment: I'd agree with @EdwinAshworth, though - it's not necessarily "when you've used a thousand words and need to make a new point". It's unrelated to the length of preceding text. It's simply a way to say "in addition to all that...", or "furthermore...". It's a matter of style as to how soon you would use it, and even whether it's that formal (I'd use it in an email, for example, but less so in speech because I'm not actually from the 19th century).

Answer (score 2):

"...to add an extra point after many points have been written," the conjuction to use is not morever, but **in addition** or **also**.

I subscribe to item no. 2 on this page [Conjunctive Adverbs (#4): Showing Added Information](http://www.eslcafe.com/grammar/conjunctive_adverbs04.html) to use **moreover** or **furthermore** "When the added information is stronger than the information preceding it."

On the same page, you will find item no. 1 which states 'When the added information is of approximately equal "strength," use **in addition** or **also**.'

Although there is but a thin line of distinction, one must exercise a deep understanding of the context in which the two or several items are to be joined. To illustrate that *moreover* and *in addition* cannot be used interchangeably:

"I have prepared all supplies that we will be needing during our travel.  In addition, I brought some presents for our hosts." **[The items mentioned are similar in degree or of the same category.]**

"The teacher reprimanded his students for their misbehavior. Moreover, she warned them that further misbehavior could cause their expulsion from the school." **[The teacher first reprimanded the students, then warned them of the worse thing to come if they misbehave again--expulsion.]**